# Doesn't $A=\sum_{j\in\mathbb N}\lambda_j\phi_j\otimes\phi_j$ imply $A$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

In the book [*An Introduction to Computational Stochastic PDEs*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/an-introduction-to-computational-stochastic-pdes/01A784303F5C86644A25BFB138923090), you can find the following assumption:

[image]

Doesn't this already imply that $A$ is bounded and hence $\mathcal D(A)=H$? By assumptio, we can write $$A=\sum_{j\in\mathbb N}\lambda_j\phi_j\otimes\phi_j\tag1$$ and the right-hand side should be bounded; at least if $\sum_{j\in\mathbb N}\lambda_j<\infty$; or is this the crucial point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$$
A=\sum_{j\in\mathbb N}\lambda_j\phi_j\otimes\phi_j
$$
with the $\{\phi_j\}$ orthonormal, then $A$ is bounded if and only if the sequence $\{\lambda_j\}$ is bounded. In fact,
$$\tag1
\|A\|=\sup\{\lambda_j:\ j\}. 
$$
This is easily seen. Indeed, any $\xi\in H$ can be written as $\xi=\sum_jx_j\,\phi_j$. Then, if $c$ is the supremum in $(1)$,
$$
\|A\xi\|^2=\Big\|\sum_j x_j\lambda_j\,\phi_j\Big\|^2=\sum_j|x_j|^2\,\lambda_j^2\leq c^2\,\sum_j\|x_j|^2=c^2\,\|x\|^2. 
$$
So $\|A\|\leq c$. Conversely, if $\{\lambda_{j_k}\}$ is a subsequence such that $\lambda_{j_k}\to c$, then
$$
\|A\phi_{j_k}\|=\lambda_{j_k}\to c, 
$$
which shows that $\|A\|\geq c$.

The condition $\sum_j\lambda_j<\infty$ is what one calls for $A$ to be *trace-class*. It does imply that $A$ is bounded, but there are many bounded operators which are not trace-class.

It is also important to know that a bounded operator that has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors is **normal**, and **selfadjoint** if the eigenvalues are real.

Comment: Note that for unbounded operators, the last paragraph is not quite true. In fact, you can always restrict the operator to the linear span of the eigenvectors, and the resulting operator is no longer self-adjoint/normal.

Comment: Fair enough, I 've edited that in. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the differential operator $A = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ acting on the Hilbert space $L^2([0, \pi])$. The domain $D(A)$ of $A$ is defined as the set of all functions $f \in L^2([0, \pi])$ that are twice differentiable and satisfy the Dirichlet boundary conditions $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$. The operator $A$ is not defined on the entirety of $L^2([0, \pi])$ because not all functions in this space satisfy these conditions.

The eigenfunctions of this operator are the sine functions $\sin(n x)$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, and the corresponding eigenvalues are $-n^2$. These sine functions form an orthonormal basis for $L^2([0, \pi])$ with respect to the $L^2$ inner product. Any function $f$ in the domain $D(A)$ can be expressed as an infinite series of these eigenfunctions:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \sin(nx)
$$

where $c_n$ are the coefficients obtained from the Fourier sine series of $f$.